# How to decorate (Active Record attribute) my primary key so it would generate as IDENTITY in SQL Server 2008

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, castle-activerecord

[image]

I am using Active Record and decorate my classes with attributes.

I have a primary key and the attribute is:

```
[PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Native, Column = "ID")]
```

Then I auto generate the table for SQL Server 2008 based on the C# class.

The result is then:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
```

....

But what I want is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
```

As you can see, the IDENTITY keyword is missing from my generated T-SQL.

What attribute should I use to be able to make my primary key IDENTITY?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are using The Castle Project Active Records. So, you need `PrimaryKeyType.Identity` attribute.
Code:

```
[PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Identity, Column = "ID")]
```